# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns' when trying to plot coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot coefficients from my means model and am getting this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

My code was originally

```
xvals = X2.columns[1:]
```

After realizing that arrays don't have columns, they have values, I changed it to .values instead, but got the error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'.

So I did some research and saw that I needed(I think) to add either loc or .iloc to it, so I finished with the below code and get the following error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc' or loc, depending which one I use. Any ideas?

```
xvals = X2.loc[1:].values

coeffs =np.exp(reg.coef_[0])-1.0

plot.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plot.bar(xvals, coeffs)
plot.xticks(rotation=90)
plot.ylabel("Coefficients [a.u.]")
plot.show()
```

Comment: I think you are confusing a numpy array with a Pandas DataFrame.  Your `X2` is a plain numpy array.  Try plotting with `X2` directly.

Comment: Almost all `AttributeError` cases involve a mistaken identity.  `columns`, `values`, `loc`, `iloc` are `pandas` dataframe attributes or methods.  If `X2` is not a dataframe none of these will work.

Comment: Thank you both. You were both right. To fix it, I started from scratch.